# Internet Explorer 8 - SCRIPT87: Invalid argument

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, google-maps

I use Google Maps and I am adding some custom buttons with JavaScript code and then apply some CSS to them.

My code displays fine in `Chrome`, `Firefox`, `IE9` browsers but in `IE8` it displays this error:

```
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument
```

The JavaScript code which applies the CSS is this:

```
var controlUI = document.createElement('div');

/* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
controlUI.style.backgroundImage = '-ms-linear-gradient(top, #A4A4A4 0%, #6B6B6B 50%)';

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
controlUI.style.backgroundImage = ' -moz-linear-gradient(top, #A4A4A4 0%, #6B6B6B 50%)';

/* Opera */ 
controlUI.style.backgroundImage = '-o-linear-gradient(top, #A4A4A4 0%, #6B6B6B 50%)';

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
controlUI.style.backgroundImage = ' -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #A4A4A4 ), color-stop(0.5, #6B6B6B))';

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
controlUI.style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A4A4A4 0%, #6B6B6B 50%)';

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
controlUI.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(to bottom, #A4A4A4 0%, #6B6B6B 50%)';

controlUI.style.borderTop = '1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)';
controlUI.style.borderBottom = '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
controlUI.style.borderRadius = '0 0 8px 8px';
```

Answer (score 1):

IE8 does not accept alpha opacity using rgba() colors, you have to use rgb();